# GPS current location

Tags: android

I've been working on this code for some time,everything seems ok but my editor,eclipse keeps telling me to cast myManager. The code is as below,

```
package com.gps.project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Button;
/*LOcation based API*/
import android.location.LocationManager;


public class GpsActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        /*Create ab ttuon we are to use in our GPS*/
        final Button gpsButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.gpsButton);
        gpsButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                LoadCoords();

            }
        });

    }
    public void LoadCoords(){
        /*Create two textfields that will contain information as latitudes and longitudes*/
        TextView latText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.latText);
        TextView lngText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.lngText);

        /*Creation of a location manager from which we are to pull the location values*/
        LocationManager myManager=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        /*To pull the coordinates from myManager, we use the getCurrentLocation( ) method.*/
        Double latPoint = myManager.getCurrentLocation("gps").getLatitude();
        Double lngPoint = myManager.getCurrentLocation("gps").getLongitude();
        /*Finally, take the new Double values and pass them to your TextViews:*/
        latText.setText(latPoint.toString());
        lngText.setText(lngPoint.toString());
    }
}
```

Will be glad if someone helps me rectify my the error. I intend to get the longitude and the latitude.

Comment: Hmm I couldn't find `getCurrentLocation`in the instance methods of `LocationManager`http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html
Should be `getLastKnownLocation` I think.

Comment: Did my answer help? Don't forget to +1 and accept if that is the case, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my reply, I think you should be using [getLastKnownLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29) insteand of `getCurrentLocation` which I couldn't find in the documentation (probably deprecated).

> Returns a Location indicating the data from the last known location
>   fix obtained from the given provider. This can be done without
>   starting the provider. Note that this location could be out-of-date,
>   for example if the device was turned off and moved to another
>   location. If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned.

The [permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#GPS_PROVIDER) that you need to add is:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: Thanx. that helped.just curios what permissions i should have added in my manifest xml file as well.

Comment: Thanx. i just uploaded another question titled uploading data to remote website....., do you think you can be of help... again?

Comment: Sure StackOverflow is all about helping other developers with their questions. But you have to start accepting answers otherwise you'll have trouble getting answers here. This is how StackOveflow works, someone takes the time to answer your question and as a thank you, you should accept answers :)